# Why this code is not printing Hi when the Enter key is pressed after stopping the code using F1 key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time
break_program = True
def on_press(key):
    global break_program
    print (key)
    if key == keyboard.Key.f1:
        print ('end pressed')
        break_program = False
        return True
    elif key == keyboard.Key.enter:
        print ('enter pressed')
        break_program = True
        return True
    else:
        return True
print("Press 'F1' key to stop the bot.")
print("Press enter to start the bot.")
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    while break_program == True:
        print('Hi')
        time.sleep(1)
    listener.join()
```

This code should stop running when `F1` is pressed and should run when `Enter` is pressed.

On pressing `Enter`, it's getting into `elif` condition and printing `enter pressed` but not printing `Hi` as `break_program` is assigned back as `True`

**Sample Output:**

```
Press 'F1' key to stop the bot.
Press enter to start the bot.
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Key.f1
end pressed
Key.enter
enter pressed
```

How the output should be:

```
Press 'F1' key to stop the bot.
Press enter to start the bot.
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Key.f1
end pressed
Key.enter
enter pressed
Hi
Hi
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a non-block thread,and your code should be :

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time
break_program = True
def on_press(key):
    global break_program
    print (key)
    if key == keyboard.Key.f1 and break_program:
        print ('end pressed')
        break_program = False

    if key == keyboard.Key.enter:
        print ('enter pressed')
        break_program = True


print("Press 'F1' key to stop the bot.")
print("Press enter to start the bot.")

listener =  keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
while True:
    if break_program:
        print("Hi")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks @jizhihaosama for your help, it worked. Can you explain to me about the block and non-block thread?

Comment: You can read about [official document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects).When you use a block thread,it won't run the next code,it will block it before the thread end.